# Disable Escape strings in Zend_Form_Element_Text elements

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I have the following piece of code:

```
// agregamos el campo de fecha de nacimiento
$this->direccion = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('direccion');
$this->direccion->setLabel('Direcci&oacute;n:');
$this->direccion->setAttrib('escape', false);
$this->direccion->getDecorator('Label')->setOption('escape',false);
$this->direccion->setRequired(true);
$this->addElement($this->direccion);
```

For some reason, while trying to setValue() to "Larrañaga", the content is escaped, and nothing is shown in the input's value. Note that setAttrib('escape', false) is applied to the element, as suggested in several posts.

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line into your `init()` method:

```
$this->getView()->setEscape('stripslashes');
```

Comment: @JoaquínL.Robles Glad to help you ;)